# when designing database if similar types of items came, we can combine both into a single table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

when designing database if similar types items came, we can combine both into a single table?

i have different types of content like(news,articles) which have similar fields like title,description and image.

so can i combine them into a single table with a type column?

**

> type   title   description
>   ----   -----   ----------- 
>   1       article1  description of article1 
>   2       news1    description of news1

**

is this standard way?

we can do like this or not?

can anyone suggest me?

thanks

Comment: Ya, this is called Single Table Inheritance and is used all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need tables such as

`item_types` ->

```
id , type

1 : article
2 : news
```

`similar_fields` ->

```
 id , title, description ,  item_types_id(FK to item_types)

 1 : this is news : This is desc : 2
```

And in your news or article table , use the  `similar_fields_id` as foreign key like

```
 article
 id ,  similar_fields_id (Fk to similar_fields table) , other_column1 , other_column2.......
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion.If suppose i don't have any other fields only(title,description). so i need to create another two tables for both news and articles? or else can i combine them into a single table without creating other two tables? is this standard way to create a single table?

Comment: @user2633530 Hi , if article and news are having SAME fields then , use table `item_types` as above(1st linein answer) . And use another table such as `news_article` . Now it will have Foreign key which points to `item_types` to show if its News or Article. Getting ?